# How can I batch rename files to folder names

Tags: windows, batch, iso-image

need some help here,
I haven't found a clear answer to this any where. I have a large amount of folders with a single iso file in each folder. The folders are named correctly but the iso's are not. All I want to do is create a batch file that will name each iso file the same name as the folder name its in and do it for all the folders in one go. can anyone help me with this? i'm using windows 10.

Comment: What about these links [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266930/how-to-rename-files-in-folders-to-foldername-using-batch-file),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357597/bulk-renaming-files-in-relation-to-the-folder-names), easily found with google? I recently had also an answer I can't find in the moment.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line (assuming current directory is your root):

```
for /r %F in (*.iso) do @for %A in ("%F\..") do ren "%F" "%~nxA.iso"
```

If you put the command within a batch script, then all percents must be doubled

```
for /r %%F in (*.iso) do @for %%A in ("%%F\..") do ren "%%F" "%%~nxA.iso"
```