# Batch Script to Rename Files to Folder Names + Custom Text

Tags: windows, batch

I have found *part* of the solution to my problem via [this](https://superuser.com/a/1204185/529800) Superuser answer, however I need the code extended to name the file in the format of: `<folder-name>+<user-defined-text>.iso`

My code so far:

```bat
for /r %%F in (*.iso) do @for %%A in ("%%F\..") do ren "%%F" "%%~nxA.iso"
```

Comment: Where does this <user defined text> come form?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `for /D /R` with `if exist files.iso`:

- ```py
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```py
  The option /D /r is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only 
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

`For /d /r` will examine all subfolders to see if there is an `.iso` file in it, if you have an `.iso` file, then run the `ren` (or move) command to rename this folder by adding it to the name and the string in variable `%custom%` (custom text + .iso)

- In your command line:

```py
for /r /d %i in (*)do if exist "%~fi\*.iso" for /f tokens^=* %I in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%~i:*.iso"')do ren "%~fI" "%~nxi_custom_name_here_%~xI"
```

- In your bat/cmd file:

```py
@echo off & setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0" & set "_custom=_your_custom_name"
for /r /d %%i in (*)do if exist "%%~fi\*.iso" for /f tokens^=* %%I in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~i:*.iso"')do ren "%%~fI" "%%~nxi %_custom% %%~xI"

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**

  [√] **[Move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Comment: The code worked! Thank you so much for your assistance, you saved me a lot of work, I needed it just for one ISO file - thank you!

Comment: @KJ318  Take a look in [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)